# the gloabl file descriptor not shared between threads on linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm working on a small c program on linux, and two threads need to use same file descriptor(actually unix domain socket), so I just set a gloabl varible of file descriptor, open file at one thread and use on the other thread, but it seems not shared, I simplify the code as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int gfd  = 0;
int test = 2;
void* thr_fun1(void* arg)
{
    printf("thr 1 gfd %d test %d \n",gfd, test);
}

int main()
{
    int gfd = open("aaa.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0664);
    pthread_t tid;
    int err;
    printf("thr main gfd %d test %d \n",gfd, test);
    test = 12;
    err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thr_fun1, NULL);
    if(0 != err)
    printf("can't create thread\n");
    sleep(2);
}
```

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64)

```
liu@ns:~$ gcc -pthread -o fd fd.c
liu@ns:~$ ./fd
thr main gfd 3 test 2
thr 1 gfd 0 test 12
```

My question is: why is the global variable `test` shared, but `gfd` is not?

Comment: Because of scope. You declare a different `gfd` inside `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the variable named `gfd` that you are printing in the thread is global, but the one you are setting in `main` is not. You declared two different variables:

1. `int gfd = 0;` This one is in fact global.
2. `int gfd = open("aaa.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0664);` This one is local to `main`.

The printout in `main` refers to #2, while the printout in `thr_fun1` sees #1.

To change this, modify the assignment in main to be an assignment, not a declaration, by removing the type:

```
gfd = open("aaa.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0664);
```